# I am new to Celery and Django,How can i store all results from the celery response in a single text file

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

here im calling the celery task, and after compleating every task i want to store the results in a single text file
**views.py**

```
urls=["https//:.....com,https//:.....com,etc.."]
for i in urls:
   r=process.delay(i)
```

**tasks.py**

```
@app.task
def process(url):
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    return r
```

Comment: what do you mean by single variable? Celery will hand off to background here and your script won't wait for response. If you want to wait and build up a list of responses then handing off to Celery might not be what you want to do.

Comment: in this case after executing one url the response will return then the the other code will continue..but not waiting the response of other urls.that was my issue,
After completing every task the complete data will stored in a text file.

Comment: do it sequentially in your views and don't use Celery for the task?

Comment: the task take more time to execute.so i use celery.